# TextMate + fontenc + hyphenation and accented characters = parsing error?

Tags: font-encodings, textmate

LaTeX compilation in TextMate sometimes throws a parsing error. Others have experienced the same problem, but AFAIK, no solution has been found yet (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837558/pb-latex-compilation-with-textmate-under-os-ventura-13 for example). This error is not related to LaTeX: the document compiles just fine using the terminal.

Now, I did investigate a bit, and it seems that the culprits may be accented characters, hyphenation and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (that I thought to be mandatory for correct hyphenation when using accented characters... )

Here is a MWE, that typesets fine when the `fontenc` package is not used, but fails when it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % If this line is commented, everything goes smoothly

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm} % A narrow minipage to force some hyphenation
   éèàéééééééù éèàéééééééù some text with accented characters
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/johndoe/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin/texmate.py", line 1054, in status = run_latex(command, filename, cache_filename, verbose) 
File "/Users/johndoe/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin/texmate.py", line 228, in run_latex fatal, errors, warnings = lp.parse_stream() 
File "/Users/johndoe/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 611, in parse_stream return super(LaTexParser, self).parse_stream() 
File "/Users/johndoe/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 195, in parse_stream line = self.get_rewrapped_line() 
File "/Users/johndoe/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 140, in get_rewrapped_line line = to_utf8(self.input_stream.readline()) 
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 77: invalid continuation byte
```

Alas, I do not know how to investigate any further. Any idea on why this is happening would be most welcome!

P.S. I'm on MacOS 12.6.3, TextMate 2.0.23 with up-to-date bundles, TeXLive 2022 (also up-to-date).

Comment: the problem is probably that something that is not utf8 is written to the log-file or to some console (it writes `[]\T1/cmr/m/n/10 éèàéééééééù` encoded in 8-bit (latin1) in my log). There was a similar looking issue once in miktex https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/581.  There is not much one can do on the latex site, report this to textmate.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike for the clues, it seems similar indeed. I have also reported to TextMate, but I tried here anyway in case someone had the issue already (and it more responsive also ;-) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone lands here: the issue has been solved (see https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues/198).